# Creating an urban dictionary command in py-rewrite?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering how i could create an urban dictionary command using discord.py rewrite. Similar to mee6 bot's one. Thank you!

I tried to find some API's for urban dictionary but was unsuccessful. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an API which can be used for Urban Dictionary, the [API is here](https://rapidapi.com/community/api/urban-dictionary) with example code on it but you can do something as simple as this:

```py
import requests

def uddef(word):
    url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"
    querystring = {"term":word}
    headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "yourkey"
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    print(response.text)



uddef("test");
```